# ActionScript 3.0 add border to movie clipe

Tags: actionscript-3

I had created the script below but the cordinate is not working right. please see my scripts and let me know what is wrong with my scripts.
thanks

```
/*mcc is the Instance name*/

var myMovieClip:Sprite = new Sprite();
trace("x" + mcc.x + "y" + mcc.y + "width" + mcc.width);
myMovieClip.graphics.lineStyle( 1, 0xFF0000 );
myMovieClip.graphics.drawRect( 0, 0, mcc.width+1, mcc.height+1 );
myMovieClip.graphics.endFill();
myMovieClip.x = -(mcc.x/2);
myMovieClip.y = -(mcc.y/2);
mcc.addChild(myMovieClip);
```

Comment: How exactly is the coordinate not working right? What is the result you are seeing from this script?

Answer (score 1):

would need to know more about `mcc` looks like we're assuming that mcc has the content centered instead of the top right corner of mcc being at [0,0]

Try using the [getBounds method](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#getBounds%28%29) instead.

something like this... though I haven't tested it

```
var bounds:Rectangle = mcc.getBounds(this)
myMovieClip.graphics.drawRect(
     bounds.left-border/2, bounds.top-border/2,
     bounds.width+border, bounds.height+border
);
myMovieClip.x = (mcc.x);
myMovieClip.y = (mcc.y);
mcc.addChild(myMovieClip);
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you, it is working now, i used the getBounds and set the myMovieClip.x = (0); . It doesn't make sense but it works good now.

Anyway, the mcc could be anything, event rotate angle too.

```
 var  border=1;
 var myMovieClip:Sprite = new Sprite();
 myMovieClip.graphics.lineStyle( border, 0xFF0000 );
 trace("getbound on mcc" + mcc.getBounds(mcc));
 trace("parser" + mcc.getBounds(mcc).y)
  trace("getbound on this" + mcc.getBounds(this));
  trace("Other x " + mcc.x + " y " + mcc.y + " width " + mcc.width+ " height " + mcc.height);
 var bounds =mcc.getBounds(mcc)
 myMovieClip.graphics.drawRect(bounds.left-border/2, bounds.top/2,bounds.width+border, bounds.height+border);

 myMovieClip.graphics.endFill();
 myMovieClip.x = (0);
 myMovieClip.y = (bounds.y)/2;
 mcc.addChild(myMovieClip);
 trace("New bound" + mcc.getBounds(mcc));
```